# R Shiny: Shiny.onInputChange working with data-toggle

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I intend to build a simple router for my shiny application. Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("landingPage"),
  tags$script(HTML(
    '$(document.body).on("click", "[navto]",
    function (e) {
      Shiny.onInputChange("navigateTo", $(e.currentTarget).attr("navto"));
    });'
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$landingPage <- renderUI({
    print(paste("Landing ", input$navigateTo))
    toOut <- pageSplashUI()
    return(toOut)
  })
}

pageSplashUI <- function() {
  tags$a(href="", navto="GotoNavPage-2", "GotoNavPage-2")
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, the *`output$landingPage`* was refreshed twice with two different *`input$navigateTo`* value after clicking the href link, the first time is the expected "***GotoNavPage-2***" while the second time is ***NULL***.

[image]

After struggling for some time, I found the issue can be resolved to add *data-toggle`="tab"* into the href. The only change is as following:

From:

```
tags$a(href="",  navto="GotoNavPage-2", "GotoNavPage-2")
```

To:

```
tags$a(href="", `data-toggle`="tab", navto="GotoNavPage-2", "GotoNavPage-2")
```

Now, the program is running as expected:
[image]

I just don't understand why does the change take effect? What's the usage of ***`data-toggle`="tab"*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is because the page actually refreshes itself every time you click on the link. It's that simple!

This will be obvious if you add a text input to the UI. Enter some text into the input, then click the link, and you'll see that the page gets refreshed.

So this is the sequence of events:

1. App starts, input is NULL, so you see "Landing  "
2. You press the link, so the input gets a value and you see "Landing  GotoNavPage-2"
3. Because the link was pressed, the page refreshed
4. App starts again (refreshed), so again you see "Landing  "

When you add `data-toggle="tab"` (or any of the other possible values in bootstrap), the Bootstrap javascript has some hooks that when you click on a link with that special attribute, it ignores it as a link, which is why you don't see this happening then.

You can simply change the href from "" to "#" which will not cause a page refresh

To be fair, it wasn't immediately clear to me that this is happening. First I spent 5 minutes being confused as to why this is happening, until I realized slowly debugged it to notice this.